# Regarding Padé Approximation of Neumann Series

Tags: approximation

I calculated the Padé Approximation of Neumann Series by hand, and then by Mathematica for different orders (from {0, 0} to some higher numbers), using the code below, in general:

```
neu = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5 + x^6 + x^7 + x^8;
PadeApproximant[neu, {x, 0, {1, 1}}]
```

I got exactly the same results. It must be good news, but according to some articles, I should get different results for different orders of this approximation. For any order higher than {1, 1}, such as {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}, ..., the result is $\frac{1}{1-x}$ (which is of course the result for the summation of an infinite number of terms of Neumann series). I just need to be sure that these results are correct and it makes sense that after {1, 1}, no progress happens in this approximation at all. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: It's a good question. But it's a math question. Voted to migrate to math.SE.

Comment: For a high enough order `PadeApproximant`, the result no longer is `1/(1-x}`.  For instance `PadeApproximant[neu, {x, 0, {8, 8}}]` returns `neu`, as one might expect.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I get $1/(1-x)$ for {8, 8}. I will be very grateful if you show that the simplified answer will be anything but $1/(1-x)$ for {8, 8}. Please send it as an answer and I accept it. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this question is posed in Mathematica format, I first answer it in Mathematica format.  Consider

```
pa = FullSimplify@PadeApproximant[f[x], {x, 0, {8, 1}}]
(* f[0] + (x*(56*(720*Derivative[1][f][0] + 
   6*x*(60*Derivative[2][f][0] + 20*x*Derivative[3][f][0] + 
   5*x^2*Derivative[4][f][0] + x^3*Derivative[5][f][0]) + 
   x^5*Derivative[6][f][0]) + 8*x^6*Derivative[7][f][0] - 
   (9*x^7*Derivative[8][f][0]^2)
   /(-9*Derivative[8][f][0] + x*Derivative[9][f][0])))/40320 *)
```

Now, for `f[x]` given by `neu`, the first eight `Derivative`s evaluated at `x = 0` are equal to `n!`, and for higher derivatives by `0`.  So, clearly the expression above cannot have a denominator proportional to `(1 - x)`.  In fact, it is given by

```
Simplify[pa /. {f[0] -> 1, Derivative[n_][f][0] -> If[n <= 8, n!, 0]}]
(* 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5 + x^6 + x^7 + x^8 *)
```

On the other hand, if `neu` were a ninth order series, then the result would be

```
Simplify[pa /. {f[0] -> 1, Derivative[n_][f][0] -> If[n <= 9, n!, 0]}]
(* 1/(1 - x) *)
```

More generally, `1/(1 - x)` is obtained for other Pade Approximations of `neu` that do not involve 9th or higher order derivatives (and, of course, have at least first order denominators).  The results were obtained with Mathematica

```
$Version
(* "13.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)" *)
```

A verbal explanation of these results is that `neu` is equal to `1/(1 - x)` near `x = 0` to eight order, but not to higher order.  So, low order Pade approximations equal `1/(1 - x)`, but high order Pade approximations are better approximated by `neu` itself.  I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is perfectly clear now. In fact, here I see a paradox. We know $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}{x^i} = \frac{1}{1-x}$, so I thought using higher orders for building the Padé Approximation would give better (high precision) results, but now I see I was wrong. By the way, I did not transfer this question to math.SE, but I apologize for the inconvenience. Thank you again.

Comment: @Ray I know that you did not move your question to this site, and no apology is needed.  I'm glad that you found my answer helpful.  Thanks for accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

The Pade approximation is a rational function that best matches the polynomial. Since 1/(1-x) already matches the terms you provide, there's nothing additional for higher-order Pade to approximate.

Another way to think of it, is the coefficients of those higher order terms happen to be zero for this particular polynomial.